# injecting new argument/property value to maven profile in module

Tags: maven

i have main pom.xml
i like to change from the main mvn command line cli which I'm using and change the :

```
<argument>${docker.image}</argument>
```

argument in only in the submodule :
module_y profile NOT module_x

this is the command I'm executing now :

mvn clean install -Ddocker_build=build

```
<artifactId>foo</artifactId>
<version>b1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

 
 <properties>
        <docker.image>www.repo.org:8000/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</docker.image>      
 </properties>
 
 <modules>
        <module>module_x</module>
        <module>module_y</module>       
 </modules>
```

this is the section in the module_x and module_y

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
       
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>docker_build</name>
                    <value>build</value>
                </property>
                <file>
                    <exists>Dockerfile</exists>
                </file>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>           
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <executable>docker</executable>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>build</argument>
                                        <argument>-f</argument>
                                        <argument>${project.basedir}/Dockerfile</argument>
                                        <argument>-t</argument>
                                        <argument>${docker.image}</argument>
                                        <argument>.</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

in short, how do i change only the property value  ${docker.image} in profile docker_build in module_y from main mvn run?

Comment: You need to change the POM for that. Is this a problem?

Comment: yes i can't all all

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the POMs, this cannot be done.

The only possible approach would be to build the modules separately (by using `-pl module_x -am` or something like that) and use different command line parameters in both cases.